# Sum of the multiplication of 2 columns in excel table

Tags: excel

table:

```
     A               B              C       
1    Item         Unit price        QTY 
2     X             2               10    
3     Y             3               20
```

Now, I need in cell `A10` to sum (Unit price * QTY) for all rows in the table.

I don't want to use any Total rows or to add a column to calculate this. I want to do it in a totally separate cell.

Is this possible? I tried but I'm getting an error. Here is my try:

```
SUM(ISSUE_ITEMS[QTY]*ISSUE_ITEMS[UNIT PRICE])
```

Comment: As long as the header values aren't included this should work with SUM......although the formula will be an "array formula" and therefore needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - `SUMPRODUCT` is preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT(ISSUE_ITEMS[QTY], ISSUE_ITEMS[UNIT PRICE])`