# Excel formula: how to get sum of calculated values?

Tags: excel

I have following data in Excel:

```
    A                B                       C
1   Task Name        Total Effort (days)     %Finished
2   Task 1           5                       30
3   Task 2           8                       25
4   Task 3           23                      18
5   Task 4           32                      5
```

All I want to get is "**=SUM(B2*C2 : B5*C5)**". But Excel doesn't allow me to do this. How do I achieve my goal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of the multiplication of 2 columns in excel table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174332/sum-of-the-multiplication-of-2-columns-in-excel-table)

Comment: What is the logic you want to perform please explain?

Comment: I don;t know why you are using a colon as a list separator. Either `=SUM(B2*C2, B5*C5)` or `=SUM(B2*C2; B5*C5)` should do depending on your own system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate, while @Olly's answer `SUMPRODUCT(B2:B5, C2:C5)` is indeed correct, however I got impression from your original post that you are a bit confused about the selectors in hand - I do believe you should study up on it before even copy-pasting any formula.

---

In excel formulas, if you are refering to a **range of cells**, you do it by declaring the range **from it's starting point, to it's ending point with a colon**.

[image]

So for example, the green range would be `A1:A5`, the blue range would be `C3:E3` and the yellow range would be `F5:G11`

Next we have separators, these seperate individual ranges *(or cells - even an individual cell is a range itself, a range with a size of 1 cell)*

[image]

For example with the following range, we would select it as `(A1:A2, A5, A7:A8)` notice the comma (`,`) acting as a separator.

---

Now as to how `=SUMPRODUCT` actually works, it takes two ranges, pits them side by side. It then does multiply the first cell of the first range with the first cell of the second range and so on. In the end, it adds them all together.

That sounds a bit difficult in words. Here is an illustration

[image]

So yes, this actually means the individual values don't even have to be side by side.

---

**Hopefully you understand now not only how your code should look like, but also why your original code didn't work! :)**

Answer (score 3):

This is simple with `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B5,C2:C5)
```